# android getIntent doInBackground

Tags: android, android-intent, android-asynctask

I am new on android. I try to get this from a activity:

```
i.putExtra("mlat", String.valueOf(latitude));
```

to here:

```
public class PostDataActivity extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>{
    GpsData gps;
//  double latitude = gps.getLatitude(); 
    //String mlat;

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
        Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
        String mlat = extras.getString("mlat");

        HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost("http://test.de");
         List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(1);
          nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("lat", mlat));
          nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("lon", "7.358154"));
           try {
            httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
           } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
           }
           try {
            httpClient.execute(httpPost);
           } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
           } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
           }
        return null;
    }
```

But getIntent ist undefined

```
Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
String mlat = extras.getString("mlat");
```

how to transfer data between the Activity and the doInBackground?

Comment: Judging by your previous questions, you still have not learnt to read documentation / think a little bit by yourself. To put you on the track: In which class is getIntent() defined?

Comment: Step2 : how do I pass arguments to a class? (hint: it has to do with constructors and member variables).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Intent does not contain anything because you are extending `AsyncTask`.
I think the approach as a whole is flawed.

Since `PostDataActivity` is meant to be an Activity, it should not extend AsyncTask.
Here is what I believe to be an idea of how it should look like:

```
public class PostDataActivity extends Activity {
GPSData gps;
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.);

    Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
    String mlat = extras.getString("mlat");

    MyDownloaderTask task = new MyDownloaderTask();
    task.execute(mlat);
}
    //Check docs for parameterisation of AsyncTask
private class MyDownloaderTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {
    protected String doInBackground(String params...) {
        string someResult;
        String mlat = params[0];
        //Got your variable, do whatever you want from here on
        return someResult; //Since it is no longer AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>
    }
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        //This executes after task completes successfully
    }
    protected void onCancelled(String result) {
        //This executes after task completes unsuccessfully
    }
}

//...
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The `execute` method of `AsyncTask` takes an array of String parameters that can be used to get extra data into the background task.

This is the example from the [Android source documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html):

```
private class DownloadFilesTask extends AsyncTask<URL, Integer, Long> {
     protected Long doInBackground(URL... urls) {
         int count = urls.length;
         long totalSize = 0;
         for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
             totalSize += Downloader.downloadFile(urls[i]);
             publishProgress((int) ((i / (float) count) * 100));
             // Escape early if cancel() is called
             if (isCancelled()) break;
         }
         return totalSize;
     }

  ..
}
```

You can call it from the main thread this way:

```
new DownloadFilesTask().execute(url1, url2, url3);
```

Answer (score 0):

First go through the tutorial provided my Matt.

For your case, you have to modify your code as below:

1.Change your argument type from void to String:

public class PostDataActivity extends AsyncTask<**String**, Void, Void>{

2.Pass your data as an argument to the AsyncTask:

new PostDataActivity().execute("**mlat**");